# Problem for rotate several shapes with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, matrix, pdfbox

I made a small java tool to generate PDF blueprints from input data, I use the PDFBox library for generation.

When I add a rectangle to my program, I would like to rotate it. For one rectangle it works well but when I have several rectangles the program doesn’t work.

To illustrate my problem, here's what I'd like to do:

[image: First screen]

And this is what my program gives :

[image: Second screen]

Clearly, I have a problem with matrix. Can anyone guide me?

Else, does anyone know a specific java library for generating blueprints?

Thank you for your help,

Code here :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

    try {
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);

        PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);

        float[] fTx = { 100, 100, 500, 340 };
        float[] fTy = { 500, 700, 700, 300 };
        Color[] cArray = { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.MAGENTA };

        int[] tAngles = { 0, -90, 180, 90 }; /* in degree */
        int angle;
        int previousAngle = 0;

        /*  */
        contents.addRect(100, 500, 400, 200);
        contents.stroke();

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

            /* transform */
            contents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(fTx[i - 1], fTy[i - 1]));
            contents.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(tAngles[i - 1] - previousAngle), 0, 0));
            previousAngle = tAngles[i - 1];
            contents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-fTx[i - 1], -fTy[i - 1]));

            /* Shapes */
            contents.setNonStrokingColor(cArray[i - 1]);
            contents.addRect(fTx[i - 1], fTy[i - 1], 100, 20);
            contents.fillAndStroke();

            contents.setNonStrokingColor(Color.GREEN);
            contents.addRect(fTx[i - 1], fTy[i - 1], 5, 5);
            contents.fillAndStroke();

        }

        /* label */
        contents.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
        contents.beginText();
        contents.newLineAtOffset(300, 400);
        contents.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 10);
        contents.showText("Test label");
        contents.endText();
        contents.closeAndStroke();

        /* End */
        contents.close();

        doc.save(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/testPDFBox.pdf");
        doc.close();

        /* Open pdf generated */
        File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/testPDFBox.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

used library  :

- fontbox-2.0.16.jar
- pdfbox-2.0.16.jar
- pdfbox-app-2.0.16.jar
- pdfbox-tools-2.0.16.jar
- preflight-2.0.16.jar
- preflight-app-2.0.16.jar
- xmpbox-2.0.16.jar

Victor.

Comment: Thanks for your (deleted by moderation but I can see it) nice answer / comment. Re 2D geometry, PDFBox has only what PDF itself has to offer. This brings some weird effects, e.g. that there is no operation for a circle, so this must be approximated with Bézier curves. (Luckily this is also explained here somewhere)

Comment: Hello Tilman. Yes it's a shame for the circles but the library is very advanced! I love it ! Indeed there is a function (homemade) with Bezier curves.  See you next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, I saved and restored the graphics state, this is easier to understand. I also adjusted the last x and y translation values and increased the upper bound of the loop.

```
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true);

//float[] fTx = { 100, 100, 500, 340 };
//float[] fTy = { 500, 700, 700, 300 };
float[] fTx = { 100, 100, 500, 500 };
float[] fTy = { 500, 700, 700, 500 };
Color[] cArray = { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.MAGENTA };

int[] tAngles = { 0, -90, 180, 90 }; /* in degree */
/* in degree */
int angle;
//int previousAngle = 0;

/*  */
contents.addRect(100, 500, 400, 200);
contents.stroke();

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    contents.saveGraphicsState();
    /* transform */
    contents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(fTx[i - 1], fTy[i - 1]));
    contents.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(tAngles[i - 1] /* - previousAngle */), 0, 0));
    //TH not needed previousAngle = tAngles[i - 1];
    contents.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-fTx[i - 1], -fTy[i - 1]));

    /* Shapes */
    contents.setNonStrokingColor(cArray[i - 1]);
    contents.addRect(fTx[i - 1], fTy[i - 1], 100, 20);
    contents.fillAndStroke();

    contents.setNonStrokingColor(Color.GREEN);
    contents.addRect(fTx[i - 1], fTy[i - 1], 5, 5);
    contents.fillAndStroke();
    contents.restoreGraphicsState();

}
```

Unrelated to the problem: You don't need all the jar files; if you have app then you don't need the individual jars. The current PDFBox version is 2.0.17.